# coin flipping distribution and probability

Tags: probability, distributions

A person is trying to claim that psychics exist by flipping a coin 10 times for each person behind a screen.  n=10 p=1/2
Its created into a one tailed test with significance level at .001. The first 999 people do not get enough right to reject the null hypothesis. But the 1000th person gets all 10 right.
if Y is the number of people out of 1000 who get all 10 coin flips right, would the distribution of y be binomial too?

Probability that one or more of the 1000 people would correctly guess 10 coin flips?

Comment: There are only $2^{10} = 1024$ possible results when the coin is tossed $10$ times, and so it is not at all surprising that one of $1000$ people did call all ten flips correctly. Do a fake experiment. Don't flip a coin at all but _pretend_ that you flipped $10$ times and got $10$ heads in a row. Will the $1000$-th person get that sequence right? I am sure that the $999$ non-psychics won't.

Comment: since the coin is being flipped 10 times in 1000 trials...wouldnt that mean there are more possible results?

Comment: No, each testee has to guess/predict only 10 coin flips, and there are only 1024 possible patterns of H and T that he can call. It is extremely unlikely that he will call 10 Heads or 10 Tails or HTHTHTHTHT or THTHTHTHTH since these are "too obviously nonrandom" (this is a psychological,not a statistical, fact)

Answer (score 3):

1. The distribution of $Y$ is indeed binomial. There are $1000$ experiments, and there is a probability of $2^{-10}$ for each person to "succeed" in guessing the coin flips. The coins are flipped for each person, so the outcome of "success / failure" for each of the potential psychics is independent. What you get is a sequence of $1000$ Bernoulli trials, with a probability of success of $2^{-10}$. In other words:
   $$ Y \sim \mathrm{bin(1000,\frac{1}{1024})}.$$
2. The probability that one or more will guess right is $1$ minus the prob. that they will all guess wrong. In other words:

$$ \Pr(\textrm{at least one guesses right}) = 1- \Pr(\textrm{everyone guess wrong}).$$
$$ \Pr(\textrm{everyone guess wrong}) = \Pr(\textrm{the first person guess wrong})^{1000} = (1-2^{-10})^{1000}.$$

Finally:
$$ \Pr(\textrm{at least one guesses right}) = 1- (1-2^{-10})^{1000} \approx 0.6235762019432771.$$